# DataBinding: 'System.Xml.linq.XElement' does not contain a property with the name 'colorName'

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

Having a hard time following other examples since they don't seem to the follow XML.  Basically I am trying to bind a list of data I am querying (LINQ to XML) to a repeater object.  Here is my xml file of focus

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<colors>
  <color>
    <id>1</id>
    <colorName>Red</colorName>
  </color>

 <color>
    <id>2</id>
    <colorName>Orange</colorName>
 </color>

  <color>
    <id>3</id>
    <colorName>Yellow</colorName>
  </color>

  <color>
    <id>4</id>
    <colorName>Green</colorName>
  </color>

  <color>
    <id>5</id>
    <colorName>Blue</colorName>
  </color>

  <color>
    <id>6</id>
    <colorName>Indigo</colorName>
  </color>

  <color>
    <id>7</id>
    <colorName>Violet</colorName>
  </color>
</colors>
```

Here is my code that will respond off the event of a dropdown selection:

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Grab data from selected index
        string color = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        string inputUrl = "C:/Users/JJ/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Colors/Colors/Xml/Colors.xml";

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputUrl))
        {
            //Read through xml file
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Creating the xml document object for use of the xml file
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(reader);

                //Creating a xDocument object for querying purposes
                XDocument colors = XDocument.Load(inputUrl);


                //List that will contain all the colors of the xml file
                XmlNodeList nameList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("colorName");
                int colorIndex = Convert.ToInt32(color)-1;

                //Will display the output in a header based off the dropdown selection
                switch (color)
                {
                    case "1":
                        outputLabel1.Text = "My favorite color is " + nameList[colorIndex].InnerXml;
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        outputLabel1.Text = "My favorite color is " + nameList[colorIndex].InnerXml;
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        outputLabel1.Text = "My favorite color is " + nameList[colorIndex].InnerXml;
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        outputLabel1.Text = "My favorite color is " + nameList[colorIndex].InnerXml;
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        outputLabel1.Text = "My favorite color is " + nameList[colorIndex].InnerXml;
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        outputLabel1.Text = "My favorite color is " + nameList[colorIndex].InnerXml;
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        outputLabel1.Text = "My favorite color is " + nameList[colorIndex].InnerXml;
                        break;
                    default:
                        outputLabel1.Text = "Please choose a color.";
                        break;
                }

                outputLabel2.Text = "List of colors remaining: ";

                var colorsLeft = from _id in colors.Descendants("colorName")
                                 //where _id.Element("id").Value != color
                                 select _id.Value;


                Repeater1.DataSource = colorsLeft;
                Repeater1.DataBind();                   
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I missing for my XElement not to know of the "colorName" property?  It's in the xml file.  Any suggestions for help/or better understanding will be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I am adding the piece for my repeater control that is suppose to bind the data.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%# Bind("colorName") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**UPDATE:**

I think I know what's going on.  Haven't had a good chance to get back at this.  I am binding two different things in my repeater control.  The first time I bind the entire XML File as a dataset and the binding recognizes the colorName property in the file.  However in my functionality where I select a different color from the dropdown list, and my query selects the remaining colors, the resultant is an IEnumerable String.  This IEnumerable only contains the text values I queried so there's no knowledge of the colorName property when I try to bind the new data.  I think this is why I'm getting the error I'm dealing with.  I could be wrong so please let me know otherwise.

So now I have to find a way to set up binding two different things.  If what I have found is the problem anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try to use xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("//color/colorName")

Comment: Do you suggest it in the query?  My apologies for not adding this but my real problem is figuring out how to select a list of remaining colors from the xml file that were not picked in the drop down list in the webapp.  Researching LINQ to XML is what I figured would be the solution since I'm trying to query for data based on a certain condition.

Comment: I am suggesting you use the full element name //color/colorName to reach teh child element.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, the problem is in the LINQ-to-XML. So I'd suggest to try this LINQ :

```
var colorsLeft = from c in colors.Descendants("color")
                 where (string)c.Element("id") != color
                 select (string)c.Element("colorName");
```

Above LINQ will select all color names string those aren't selected in the dropdownlist.

Mmm.. but I don't really understand how this relates to the error message you posted as the question title..

**UPDATE :**

Turned out that you have another problem which I think is in your binding statement. The binding expect binding source is a collection of object having property named `colorName`. You can either change your binding or change the LINQ to fix the error.

Since I can't see your binding, I can only give example for the latter :

```
var colorsLeft = from c in colors.Descendants("color")
                 where (string)c.Element("id") != color
                 select new { colorName = (string)c.Element("colorName") };
```

Above LINQ return collection of anonymous object having single property, `colorName`.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance but now I'm getting the same error pertaining to a string

DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'colorName'.

Comment: Yeah that's what I started thinking last night.  Here's my piece in the aspx page for the repeater control.

    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%# Bind("colorName") %>' />